# Is possible to compress ALL the web browsing using a ssh tunnel or similar?

Tags: browser, compression, ssh-tunnel

I have a machine with a fast connection to internet in point A (Let's say 10MB).

In point B I have a machine with slow internet (let's say 1/2 MB).

Is possible to use a ssh tunnel that run in point A, compress the data (ie: HTML, JS, CSS, etc), and deliver it faster to point B?

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
ssh -C -o 'CompressionLevel 9' -D8888 <servername>
```

which establishes a SOCKS5-proxy on localhost's port 8888 requesting highest compression level.  Then you can configure your browser to use this Socks-Proxy.